# How to reset a systemd timer?

Tags: systemd

Somehow my ubuntu got confused and it set the time a month ahead. apt-daily.timer got triggered and run at the false time. <s>Now the time is correct but as the timer ran in the future, `systemctl list-timers` say apt-daily.timer will run again in a month!</s>

I need to find a way to solve this.

I've looked at the wrong column -last- in `systemctl list-timers`.

I should have looked at "next". As the answer, I guess it got corrected automatically. So the question was tainted. I am sorry.

I guess stopping and starting resets the timer too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would expect timers to be corrected automatically but as you indicate this is not happening try:

```
systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
systemctl start apt-daily.timer
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but my question was tainted, sorry about that, fixing it right now. I checked out the wrong column in systemctl list-timers, last run. I should've checked next. I've reboot and restarted the timer, It is planned correctly now. Thank you.